# c++ clicker doesn't work a certain program is running

Tags: c++, input, click, mouse, send

I am making a basic clicker. It usually works fine but whenever i have rust open it doesn't click anymore (doesnt matter if its windows or fullscreen), btw rust is a survival game that needs a lot of clicking when crafting.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <winable.h>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void LeftClick();
void mouseLeftClick();
std::string getFileContents(std::ifstream& File);

int main()
{
    HWND target = GetForegroundWindow();

    POINT pt;
    RECT wrect;

    //Stealth();
    char i;

    int ms = 0;
    //int key = 70;
    char cKey = 'F';
    int key = toupper(cKey);

    cout << "how long to wait before next click? (in Milliseconds)\n";
    cout << "Delay: ";
    cin >> ms;
    cout << "Delay set to " << ms << "\n";
    cout << "What key do you want to press to activate the clicking?\n";
    cout << "Key: ";
    cin >> cKey;
    cout << "Key set to " << char(toupper(cKey)) << "\n";
    cout << "ASCII: " << key;

    while (1)
    {
        for (i = 8; i <= 190; i++)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
            {
                int key_stroke = i;

                if (key_stroke == toupper(cKey))
                {
                    GetCursorPos(&pt);
                    GetClientRect(target, &wrect);
                    mouseLeftClick();
                    cout << char(toupper(key_stroke)) << endl;
                    Sleep(ms);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void mouseLeftClick()
{
    INPUT Input =
    { 0 };

    // left down
    Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    ::SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));

    // left up
    ::ZeroMemory(&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
    Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    ::SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

any help is appreciated :D

Comment: The issue seems when rust is running it uses mutex to lock the resource which is listening to hooks registered. I see you have not registered a hook  for your application as a result you dont get an exclusive access which maybe rust does.

Below 2 links may be of help to you 
1) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx 
2) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67091/Mouse-and-KeyBoard-Hooking-utility-with-VC

Comment: wouldn't the hook just listen to the messages sent?